# error al subir archivo txt en gridview c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo este error al momento de cargar nuevamente el mismo archivo.txt al hacerlo la primera vez si me lo muestra sin ningún problema la segunda vez me arroja un error que le archivo esta siendo utilizado e probado varios métodos y nada este es el código que uso para subir el archivo

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        if (ChecarExtension(FileUpload1.FileName))
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(@"C:\texto/" + FileUpload1.FileName);


            Label1.Text = FileUpload1.FileName + " cargado exitosamente";

            lblOculto.Text = (@"C:\texto/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Error al subir el archivo o no es el tipo .txt";
    }

    try
    {

        CargarDatos(lblOculto.Text);
    }
    catch
    {
        Response.Write("Ocurrio un error debe cargar antes el archivo");
    }
}
```

código cargar datos

```
   private void CargarDatos(string strm)
{
    DataTable tabla = null;
    StreamReader lector = new StreamReader(strm);
    String fila = String.Empty;
    Int32 cantidad = 0;
    do
    {
        fila = lector.ReadLine();
        if (fila == null)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (0 == cantidad++)
        {
            tabla = this.CrearTabla(fila);
        }
        this.AgregarFila(fila, tabla);
    } while (true);

    GridView1.DataSource = tabla;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Después de usarlo por primera vez usas el Close para cerrar el archivo?

Comment: no lo eh usado en que parte del codigo tengo que usarlo?

Comment: Adjunta el codigo de CargarDatos

Comment: ok ya modifique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice esto rapido para probar y funciona todas las veces sin error

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.FileName);
    string strLinea = "";
    ArrayList arrText = new ArrayList();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Valor", typeof(System.String));
    DataRow row;

    while (strLinea != null)
    {
        row = table.NewRow();
        strLinea = objReader.ReadLine();
        if (strLinea != null)
        {
            row["Valor"] = strLinea;
            table.Rows.Add(row);       
        }
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    objReader.Close();
    objReader.Dispose();
}
```

Proba agregando

```
objReader.Close();
objReader.Dispose();
```

En tu caso la variable lector

Comment: gracias amigo al principio no me tomaba bien los errores tenia que limpiar cache de la web muchas gracias ya funciona aprovechando este link conoces algún metodo para cuando le de click a una linea del grid me los pase a unos label

Comment: Eso seria un evento, si haces click en el DataGrid tenes un botón con una imagen de un rayo que es el de eventos, ahí tenes todos los que tiene el objeto @darksihart